# Sort log messages

Tags: php, file, magento

Hello everyone I'm trying to sort my log messages from files.
My log file looks like this
http://kopy.io/tA8bv 
I want to achive something like this

```
['debug'] => [
    ['logs'] => [
        ['log message'] => [
            '2016-04-10',
            '2016-04-10',
            '2016-04-10'
        ],
        ['log message'] => [
            '2016-04-10',
            '2016-04-10',
            '2016-04-10'
        ],
        ...
    ]
],
['Crit'] => [
    ['logs'] => [
        ['log message'] => [
            '2016-04-10',
            '2016-04-10',
            '2016-04-10'
        ],
        ['log message'] => [
            '2016-04-10',
            '2016-04-10',
            '2016-04-10'
        ],
        ...
    ]
]
```

Here is my code but it doesnt work correctly it ommits some lines

```
$file = fopen(self::DIRECTORY.$filename, 'rb');
while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    if($this->lineHasDate($line)) {
        $logDate = $this->getLogDate($line);
        $logType = $this->getTypeOfLog($line);
        $content .= $line;
        // $content ='';
    }
    while(!$this->lineHasDate($line) && ($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        // echo $line;
        $content .= $line;
    }
    $this->logs[$logType]['logs'][] = $content;
    $content = '';
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: It's hard to suggest anything without knowing how `lineHasDate` looks like and which lines are omitted.

Comment: `lineHasDate` check if current line in file has date if true then its new log message. My code ommits for example this line `2016-09-19T15:16:27+00:01 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/media/js.phtml
`

Comment: The link is dead. Can you repost a snippet within this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specified code - looping through file inside a loop through file, - is a bit too complicated and more prone to errors.

Try it like this, it works for me on your example. It's more straightforward and simpler to read and to debug:

```
$file = fopen (self::DIRECTORY.$filename, 'rb');
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false)
{
    if ($this->lineHasDate($line))
    {
        $logDate = $this->getLogDate($line);
        $logType = $this->getTypeOfLog($line);

        $this->logs[$logType]['logs'][] = $line;
        $currentLog = &$this->logs[$logType]['logs'][count($this->logs[$logType]['logs']) - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        if (!isset($currentLog)) // In case of trash lines before logs begin
            continue;
        else
            $currentLog .= $line;
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

Also, test that `$this->lineHasDate($line)` returns `true` when you feed it the omitted lines.

Comment: Before each loop you take a new line. If it contains a date, then this is a new log entry, so a new element of value `$line` is added to the `'logs'` array of the appropriate `$logType`. And then you save the reference to this string for appending next lines to it if they don't contain a date.

Comment: It works thank you very much. Wil it work for big files I mean over 1gb? How will function looks if I want to determine if in array is the same log message as in file if its true then add date for this log. Message of log should be new index in array and dates of occurs should be in this array. I've edited question.